# Is there any way to fetch data at obj obj in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, nested, reactive

Is there any way to fetch data (by id) at obj obj ?

example:

```
  hello(){
    this._shelveService.getShelveDataById(this.route.snapshot.params.id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);

  this._shelveForm = this.fb.group({
    id_shelve:[data['id_shelve']],
    description_shelve:[data['description_shelve']],
    war_id:this.fb.group({
      id_warehouse: [data['war_id.id_warehouse']]
    })
 })
    })
  }
```

**how to get the value of id_warehouse ?**

I can get the value id_shelve and description_shelve with the **hello() function** but if I type:

```
war_id:this.fb.group({
  id_warehouse: [data['war_id']]
```

**i get as a result Obj Ojb**

json :

```
{
    "id_shelve": 1,
    "description_shelve": "Περιγράφη Ραφίου!!!",
    "war_id": {
        "id_warehouse": 1,
        "description_warehouse": "Περιγράφη Αποθήκης!!!"
    }
}
```

Any help;

Comment: Could you please clarify the question, and what do you expect to get exactly?

Comment: @AmerYousuf i change it please help me :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by either of the two approaches below:

a) Dot notation:

```
this._shelveForm = this.fb.group({
    id_shelve: [data['id_shelve']],
    description_shelve: [data['description_shelve']],
    war_id: this.fb.group({
        id_warehouse: [data.war_id.id_warehouse],
        description_warehouse: [data.war_id.description_warehouse]
    })
});
```

b) Square bracket notation:

```
this._shelveForm = this.fb.group({
    id_shelve: [data['id_shelve']],
    description_shelve: [data['description_shelve']],
    war_id: this.fb.group({
        id_warehouse: [data['war_id']['id_warehouse']],
        description_warehouse: [data['war_id']['description_warehouse']]
    })
});
```

Comment: you are a truly legend i was dealing with this issue about 5 hours,I'm so noob :(

Comment: Being a newbie/noob is not a bad thing, as long as you're a constant learner! Btw, there are certain situations in which what you tried to do initially might have sense. For eg if one of the fields inside the JSON data contains a dot in its name.  For more details over this, you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/5780536

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
war_id:this.fb.group({
  id_warehouse: [data['war_id']]
```

with

```
war_id:this.fb.group({
  id_warehouse: [data['war_id']['id_warehouse']]
```